# How to changing the field datatypes in elasticsearch using the Mapping API or reindexing

Tags: elasticsearch

How to changing the field datatypes using the Mapping API or reindexing In Elasticsearch.

Comment: Hi any one please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

I am new to Elasticsearch but faced similar problem. According to my understanding once a mapping is decided for a index it cannot be changed.

Please check the following link:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/mapping-intro.html

"We can update a mapping to add a new field, but we can’t change an existing field from analyzed to not_analyzed."

But what you can do is update the mapping of a new field. So you can change the datatype of the data and save it again as a new field.